# Compare one value to next value in a sorted dictionary

Tags: c#

I have a sorted dictionary having names as key and marks as value.

```
Dictionary<string,int> diM = new Dictionary<string,int>();
```

Another dictionary to store time taken by respective student.

```
Dictionary<string,int> diT = new Dictionary<string,int>();
```

Now if the marks of the two students are same then ranking based on time taken.

```
var marks = from pair in diM
            orderby pair.Value descending
            select pair;
int j=0;

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in marks)
{
    j++;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",j, pair.Key);
}
```

Now if one student marks are equal with next student marks (as sorted Dictionary) then student with less time should be output.

Comment: First: welcome to stack overflow!  Second: there's a bit of a contradiction in your question's phrasing.  "If one student marks are equal with next then student with less marks should be output" <-- how can "equal" and "less" be true in the same iteration?

Comment: What happens if two students have the same name. Key should be unique. Try using studenId or something similar

Comment: Just for some correction. The dictionaries are not "sorted dictionary". They are just a normal dictionary :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** I'd recommend not using dictionaries for this task. Create a class with properties of name, mark and time. Something like:

```
public class TestResult
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
}
```

Then hold a list of that type. Whenever you have two separate collections which you somehow need to keep in sync - suspect that there might be a problem in the design.

---

As for the actual problem, use Linq to join the two dictionaries by the key. Once you did that you can order the results by the mark and then by the time:

```
var result = from mark in diM
             join time in diT on mark.Key equals time.Key
             orderby mark.Value descending, time.Value
             select new { Name = mark.Key, Grade = mark.Value, Time = time.Value };
```

Comment: If it's "time taken" then `TimeSpan` is probably preferred over `DateTime`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - That is true :) Thanks

Comment: thanks for the answer!! the above Linq will take both time and mark into consideration but time should be compared only when the marks are same.

Comment: @ShaniBhati - It will first order by mark. Then only in the case of two marks that are the same the time matters.